# How to resolve the error in Odoo 8?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

Recently I had restored a Odoo DB to a newly created instance, From then on i am getting the following error whenever I go to the respective menu :

KeyError: u'mro.request'

How to resolve such kind of errors?

Any suggestion would be really helpful. Thanks!!

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 517, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 538, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 294, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 291, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 754, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 387, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 1251, in load
    action = request.session.model(action_type).read([action_id], False, ctx)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/http.py", line 856, in proxy
    result = meth(cr, request.uid, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 326, in read
    results = super(ir_actions_act_window, self).read(cr, uid, ids, fields=fields, context=context, load=load)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 3083, in read
    result = BaseModel.read(records, fields, load=load)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 3115, in read
    self._read_from_database(stored)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/models.py", line 3279, in _read_from_database
    res2 = self._columns[f].get(cr, self._model, ids, f, user, context=context, values=result)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 1356, in get
    result = self._fnct(obj, cr, uid, ids, name, self._arg, context)
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py", line 265, in _search_view
    field_get = self.pool[act.res_model].fields_view_get(cr, uid,
  File "/home/administrator/second2/apps/odoo/lib/odoo-8.0_a2115ef-py2.7.egg/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 101, in __getitem__
    return self.models[model_name]
KeyError: u'mro.request'
```

Comment: Is there a full error traceback? Any other context?

Comment: Klaus D, i managed to solve the above problem, Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the above problem by upgrading the modules which were in the dependencies.

Comment: I suggest you to choose this as answer and close the question

Comment: can you accept it as answer?, since stack overflow does not allow me to do so